# PostgreSQL: Efficiently return table in PL/pgSQL function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have the following use case: A user needs to query a table that is currently being created, and therefore does not yet exist in the catalog.

Therefore, I have implemented a PL/pgSQL function that blocks until the table is available (by polling the `information_schema.tables`). When the table is available, it returns the table tuples by calling the return query `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE SELECT * FROM table`.

This is somehow inefficient, as *the current implementation of RETURN NEXT and RETURN QUERY stores the entire result set before returning from the function* (as stated in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html).

**Is there any more efficient way of returning the table result through the function?**

I think I am after a functionality similar to the Oracle `RETURN PIPELINED` mode, where the result is "streamed" to the user without first completely building up the result within the function, as with `RETURN NEXT` in PostgreSQL.

If this is not possible through this particular function, is there any other way of achieving the desired functionality?

Answer (score 0):

There is an possibility what you want, but only on C API level.

But your use case looks strange, these operations are not good to implement on SQL level.

Comment: You are right, usually this should be done on the application level. However, this is a special use case, for which I am looking for a solution that can be handled by the DBMS itself.

Comment: @harry_g - you can do it only in low level language, that can use C API

Comment: Do you mean implementing a function using the C API instead of PL/pgSQL?

Comment: yes https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-c.html#XFUNC-C-RETURN-SET